# ORA-00922: missing or invalid option on changing the user password

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

This plsql is returning the error:

> ORA-00922: missing or invalid option

```
DECLARE
BEGIN

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER upper(:USERNAME) IDENTIFIED BY :NEW_PASSWORD REPLACE :OLD_PASSWORD';

END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

DDL statements where ALTER belongs to cannot contain bind variables - :USERNAME, :NEW_PASSWORD, :OLD_PASSWORD

Use

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER USER ' || upper(:USERNAME) || ' IDENTIFIED BY ' || :NEW_PASSWORD || ' REPLACE ' || :OLD_PASSWORD;
```

instead.

Comment: This is subject to SQL injection.

Comment: Dynamic SQL always is, so use carefully or change the approach to be more secure.

Comment: @Husqvik, "always" is too strong and actually weakens Shannon's appropriate warning. Dynamic SQL is only vulnerable to SQL injection if user-entered data is concatenated into it. In this case, definitely, and dangerously so.